# How to get publish_stream permissions for app to post in the wall of a Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I created an application that connects to Facebook from server-side. I opened a page (Community Page) in order to the app make posts on the wall of this page with GRAPH API.
When I try to post in the page via PAGEID/feed , I receive back this response:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

I've seen it on the pages of Facebook applications like Photos, Events or Notes show "Extended Permissions", but when I add my application as a tab does not appear that option.

I´m frustated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) documentation?

Comment: Yes, Igy, but I don´t try to add the tab programatically. I just add the app using //www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxxx... After this.. Facebook add the application as Tab in that page, but I can´t to get the publish_stream permissions...

Comment: Adding the app has a tab has nothing to do with your ability to post updates to that page's timeline - are you obtaining the correct permissions from the page admin?

Comment: mmm... Do you mean that I need to get a access_token for the page administrator to be able to post updates and not for the application? Currently I get the permissions for the app and next I try to do the update..

Answer (score 0):

You need the admin of the page to grant your app [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) to access their pages.

There's an entire section of the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation devoted to this: [Authenticating as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/)

Once you have the `manage_pages` permissions from the user, a call to `/me/accounts` will return a list of the pages that user administers along with an `access_token` you can use to make API calls on behalf of the page.

Comment: Finally, I have to look for another solution.. :( The response will be to save my own auth_token (I´m the admin) when I log through the app and reuse it in a cron process in order to be able to post to the page programatically. Facebook needs an user token and the only way to get that token is making a login interactively. For others interested in the same problem, there is a [Offline Access Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) that explain all about the long-live auth tokens. Thanks @Igy.